# Why are question titles a link to the same question?

Tags: discussion, design

Recently, while looking at questions, I noticed that the top of the question had title, but hovering over it, I realized that it was a link. Clicking it goes to the same question, and further research shows that the link is exactly the same as the question URL.

I think that this is rather useless, as the title can simply be a header, with a link being unnecessary.

Comment: I use it as a refresh. It is good for certain aspects which are not live updated.

Comment: I use it to get clean links to posts when there's something ugly in the querystring.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188608/why-is-the-question-title-a-link-that-just-takes-you-back-to-the-question-you-ar

Answer (score 4):

> *"I think that this is rather useless"*

It actually isn't, because there are [other links leading to that site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288652/why-are-question-titles-a-link-to-the-same-question/288653#288653), and you might want to easily clean them up, before using them in a related post or duplicate.